# Is it possible to send data from phonegap using AJAX to update mysql table

Tags: mysql, ajax, cordova

I have an HTML5 app in which i am using ajax to update the mysql data base table and it works fine but when i convert HTML5 app to phonegap it does not update the mysql data is it possible to update in phonegap or not.

Comment: where is your mysql database? In server? Show the ajax call code that you used in phonegap.

Comment: It's fully possible to make external ajax calls. Could it be a CORS (cross-domain) problem, with your locally run html calling an external domain? Impossible to help you further without code, as @AtanuCSE  already stated.